# Show knitr-RNW document structure in Kile

Tags: kile, knitr

When working with a knitr file (RNW document) on Kile the document structure isn't shown in the structure view, even though it contains a valid LaTeX structure of parts, sections etc. If I change the file suffix into `.tex` then the structure is shown, but it's a bad idea because I need to compile it later into a real LaTeX document. Is there any way to trick Kile into showing the structure of an RNW file?

Comment: RNW files are the ones used by [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) to weave R code chunks into a LaTeX document.

Comment: You can search for `Kile` in the documentation for editors and follow the instructions: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/

Comment: I know Marek's website, but his instructions refer only to how to add the knitting command to Kiles build options and for opening and saving but that doesn't make kile read the file structure.

Comment: @RoeyAngel OK, I thought the bullet point 2 `Automatic syntax highlighting of .Rnw sources` should help; sounds like it does not. I do not use Kile, so I do not really know...

Comment: I think, but not sure, that `Automatic syntax highlighting of .Rnw sources` makes kile highlight the LaTeX part of the document (but not the R parts) and it also doesn't detect the structure. My new workaround for the structure issue is to save the `.rnw` document with a `.ltx` instead (which kile recognizes).

Comment: @RoeyAngel I imagine it is not trivial for Kile to support syntax highlighting for both LaTeX and R in the Rnw document, but you can file a feature request to the developers anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for an editor (Kile).